# ionic 2 event after modal onDidDismiss()

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic2

I'm quite new to Ionic 2 development and would like your help. Does anyone know how what event comes after onDidDismiss() ?

```
presentProfileModal() {
   let profileModal = this.modalCtrl.create(Profile, { userId: 8675309 });
   profileModal.onDidDismiss(data => {
     console.log(data);
   });
   profileModal.present();
 }
```

I would know how to store the parameter to parent's properties after `onDidDismiss()` from a modal page.

---

Edited:
So this is my actual codes which I can't solve. While debugging using vs2015, the parent component appears undefined after I am calling `this.viewCtrl.dismiss(this.calibration)` and my breakpoint was in onDidDismiss() event. Inside `data` has values but I can't store the results to the parent component.

[Parent Component Undefined Error Image][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/12TVj.png

This is the code to create my modal:

```
public goToCalibration(calibration, seqNo) {
        this.selectedCalibrationTask = seqNo;
         let modal = this.modalCtrl.create(ModalCalibrationPage, { "calibration": calibration });
         modal.onDidDismiss(data => {
             this.value = data;
            //for (var i = 1; i < this.task.TaskItems.length; i++) {
            //    if (this.task.TaskItems[i].SeqNo == this.selectedCalibrationTask) {
            //        if (data != null) {
            //            this.task.TaskItems[i].Calibration = data;
            //        }

            //        break;
            //    }
            //}
            
        });
        modal.present();
    }
```

Modal TS code:

```
export class ModalCalibrationPage {
    public calibration: any;

    public constructor(public viewCtrl: ViewController, private navParams: NavParams) {
        if (this.navParams.get("calibration") != null) {
            this.calibration = this.navParams.get("calibration");
        }
        else {
            this.calibration = {
                EquipmentBefore: '',
                InstrumentBefore: '',
                ControlRoomBefore: '',
                EquipmentAfter: '',
                InstrumentAfter: '',
                ControlRoomAfter: '',
                StandardSignal: {
                    Std1: '',
                    Std2: '',
                    Std3: '',
                    Error1: '',
                    Error2: '',
                    Error3: ''
                },
                BeforeCalibration: {
                    Std1: '',
                    Std2: '',
                    Std3: '',
                    Error1: '',
                    Error2: '',
                    Error3: ''
                },
                AfterCalibration: {
                    Std1: '',
                    Std2: '',
                    Std3: '',
                    Error1: '',
                    Error2: '',
                    Error3: ''
                },
                MeasuredVoltage: '',
                StandardType: '',
                UOM: '',
                InstrumentAccuracy: '',
                InstrumentCalibrated: false,
                Remarks: ''
            };
        }
    }

    public dismiss() {
        this.viewCtrl.dismiss();
    }

    public saveCalibration() {
        this.viewCtrl.dismiss(this.calibration);
    }
}
```

Comment: _Data has values but i can store the results to the parent component._ do you mean it returns actual values but it is not getting set or _undefined is returned_?

Comment: Sorry there was a typo "but i can't store"

Comment: and yes it returns actual values input by users but its not getting set.

Comment: I think you are simply checking this.value too early.. why not just console log it? `console.log(JSON.stringify(this.value,undefined,2))`

Comment: All right i will check it thanks Suraj.

Comment: Hi Suraj, you are totally right. Even though i'm debugging in visual studio, during 'this.value' appears undefined, but i am still able to store values. After following your method i was able to solve my problem. Thanks alot !!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to set `data` in parent component.
You should have a class property in the parent and set within the data value *within* `onDidDismiss()` callback.

```
value:any;

presentProfileModal() {
   let profileModal = this.modalCtrl.create(Profile, { userId: 8675309 });
   profileModal.onDidDismiss(data => {
     console.log(data);
     this.value=data;//here
     console.log(JSON.stringify(this.value,undefined,2));
   });
   profileModal.present();
 }
```

In the modal you send in ViewController's `dismiss()` function.
`this.viewCtrl.dismiss(data)`

Comment: Hi Suraj, thanks for your swift reply. I have tried that before but in my actual code i got this issue with the parent component have "undefined"

Comment: where are you printing the value? also did you make sure you are returning it correctly? given the info I can tell

Comment: All right suraj will edit my question and add more details so you can get a better picture.

Comment: After `console.log(JSON.stringify(this.value,undefined,2))`, i have manage to determine that there is still data stored in the Parent's component. So this answer really works thanks suraj !

Answer (score 0):

This is what my answer is after applying suraj solution. I only could assign the results to the parent component after `onDidDismiss()` event and not manipulate any data. So i hope this could help someone who face the same issue as me.

 
Parent's TS Code:

```
public selectedCalibrationTask: any;
public selectedSeqNo: any;

public goToCalibration(seqNo) {

    if (this.selectedSeqNo == null)
    {
        this.selectedSeqNo = seqNo;
    }   

    let modal = this.modalCtrl.create(ModalCalibrationPage, { "calibration": this.selectedCalibrationTask, "seqNo": this.selectedSeqNo });

     modal.onDidDismiss(data => {
         this.selectedCalibrationTask = data.calibration;
    });
    modal.present();
}
```

Modal's TS Code:

```
public saveCalibration() {
        this.viewCtrl.dismiss(this.calibration);
    }
```